# Converting a value to a different output other than a string or number using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you convert a value, gotten from inputs using val(), into something other than a string or number? There are 4 boxes already (by default).

```
<html>
<body>
   <div class="container">
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
       <label for="numberOfCircles">Enter the number of circles:</label>
       <input type="text" id="numberOfCircles" />
       <button type="button" id="changeNumberOfCircles">Submit</button>
   </div>

   <script>scripts/jquery.js</div>
   <script>
       $(function(


       )); // end ready
</body>
</html>
```

If the user types 10 into the text field and clicks Submit, I want it to show 10 boxes. How do I do that using jQuery methods such as clone() or append() etc?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will always be asked to show your implementations attempts.

Comment: What I did didn't make any sense: All I did was this `var $noOfCircles = $('#changeNumberOfCircles').val()` and then I didn't know what to do. @Stphane

Comment: Oh no, it is the answer to my question. Thank you again. I just wanted her to know my previous attempts were so pathetic, I didn't bother putting it up in the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get value from the `input` field then loop through it and append values in the container (check code snippet)

```
var item = $('#numberOfCircles').val();

for ( var count = 0; count < item; count++ ) {
    $('.container').append('<div class="boxes"></div>');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('body').on('click', '#changeNumberOfCircles', function() {
      var item = $('#numberOfCircles').val();
    
      $('.container').empty();
    
      for (var count = 0; count < item; count++) {
          $('.container').append('<div class="boxes"></div>');
      }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
  
.boxes {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
   <div class="submit">
       <label for="numberOfCircles">Enter the number of circles:</label>
       <input type="text" id="numberOfCircles" />
       <button type="button" id="changeNumberOfCircles">Submit</button>
   </div>

   <div class="container">
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
        <div class="boxes"></div>
   </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

### Another solution from the comments

On selection of checkboxes add `rating-chosen` class to the `div` and after that`#selectedBoxes` on click event check the `div` contains `rating-chosen` class to increment one in a variable, just to display alert message `alert('You selected ' + selectedBoxCount + ' out of ' + boxCount);`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('body').on('click', '#changeNumberOfCircles', function() {
      var item = $('#numberOfCircles').val();
    
      $('.container').empty();
    
      for (var count = 0; count < item; count++) {
          $('.container').append('<div><input class="checkbox left" type="checkbox" /><div class="boxes"></div></div>');
      }
  });
  
  $('body').on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
    
      $this.siblings('.boxes').toggleClass('rating-chosen');
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', '#selectedBoxes', function() {
      var selectedBoxCount = 0,
          boxCount = $('.container .boxes').length;
      
      $.each($('.boxes'), function( index, item ) {
          if ( $(item).hasClass('rating-chosen') ) {
              selectedBoxCount++;
          }
      });
      
      alert('You selected ' + selectedBoxCount + ' out of ' + boxCount);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
  
.boxes {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.submit {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.rating-chosen {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
     <div class="submit">
         <label for="numberOfCircles">Enter the number of circles:</label>
         <input type="text" id="numberOfCircles" />
         <button type="button" id="changeNumberOfCircles">Submit</button>

         <button type="button" id="selectedBoxes">Get selected boxes</button>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
          <div><input class="checkbox left" type="checkbox" /><div class="boxes"></div></div>
          <div><input class="checkbox left" type="checkbox" /><div class="boxes"></div></div>
          <div><input class="checkbox left" type="checkbox" /><div class="boxes"></div></div>
          <div><input class="checkbox left" type="checkbox" /><div class="boxes"></div></div>
     </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the user types 10 into the text field and clicks Submit, I want it to show 10 boxes. How do I do that using jQuery methods such as clone() or append() etc? So you can use the above code for it but what do you mean by different output other then string or number, could you please give me an example?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wondered how I was going to do it without including for loop statements but I guess there's no easier way. As per the last question I asked, the for loop statement answers it. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help you and please upvote/accept the answer!

Comment: Hi again! I have another problem. I'm trying to use the post() method to retrieve whatever maxvalue the user inputs and whatever number of circles the user clicks. For example, if the user wants 7 boxes but only selects 5 nd clicks Save Data, the message shown after should be 'You selected 5 out of 7'. Here is the code:

Comment: I added them to the answer you provided:                                                    
    `$('body').delegate('.rating-circle', 'click', function() {
                  var $deleMouse = $(this);
                  $deleMouse.addClass('rating-chosen');              
              });`

Comment: @TheLadyDothCodeTooMuch could you please update your question or post another (new) one!

Comment: Hi, I'll answer your question once you're done with editing :)

Comment: `$('#save-rating').click(function() {
          var person = new Object; 
          var maxValue: $('#max-value').val();
          var value: 
          $.post('http://jquery-edx.azurewebsites.net/api/Rating', person).done(function () {
            $('#output').text('You selected ' + value + ' out of ' + maxValue);
          });
        });` The Save Data button was giving an id of save-rating. My question is, how do I get the number of circles the user chooses/clicks (the empty `value` variable) out of the total number of circles (`maxValue`)? Thank you again. :) Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I also noticed something. Once I try to load the page on the browser, none of it works, even the first part where the user gets to determine the total number of circles to be displayed. However, when I comment out the entire $.post() method, everything else works perfectly. Do you have any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: first of all replace colon : with equal sign = `var maxValue:`... actually I'm not getting it, what exactly do you want to do here? What is number of circles? and why are you using $.post method? Is everything stored on server?

Comment: Well, I thought you just want to show alert message of selected divs out of total divs on browser side.. but I'm just wondering what's the purpose of using $.post here? Well, let me update my answer may be you'll get some idea from that..